# Keep capabilities when chromedriver opens new tab

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

On my tests I create a chrome driver window emulating a given device. So far no problem.

The issue is when I click on a button on my website and this button navigates to a new tab. This new tab is not keeping the device screen resolution properties, meaning it opens in full resolution.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try ctrl+click?Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
element.click();
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

Comment: but that will open another windows wouldn't? The issue is exactly that, a new window and/ior tab will open in full screen

Comment: ha I understand .. I could not find any resources but I found a add on not sure if you would be interested in it

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/theone-open-link-in-same/jmphljmgnagblkombahigniilhnbadca?hl=en

Comment: Hi. Not an 'expected solution' but solved my problem! Thanks :D